# Implement a login view controller

Tags: ios, authentication, storyboard

i'm developing an app in Objective-C with Xcode 7 for iOS 9 compatible devices, and I'm finding some difficulty in the login section. How should my storyboard be to show the login view controller as root view if the user is not already logged in?
In this app, the root view controller is a simple view controller with a segue to a navigation controller that holds two simple view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I handle login is to have the login view controller embedded in a navigation controller.  It is the initial view controller shown when the app runs.

I set a BOOL variable in NSUserDefaults called LoggedIn and check it every time the app is opened in viewDidLoad of the login view controller.  If the variable = NO show the login view controller, and if the variable = YES push to the next view controller (animated:NO) so the first thing the user sees is the screen you want them on.

In your login view controller viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"LoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: And if I want to consider the login system (login view -> signin view) separate from my main controller as standalone, how can I code the AppDelegate.m for this purpose? Like, if user is logged in the root view controller is this, else the root view controller is this other.

Comment: Using the method I posted, do it the same way but instead of pushing the view controller after checking the flag, present a new view controller. I added some code, its really simple to just check and present the view controller you would like.

Comment: presenting the login view controller, i'm getting the error "view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Answer (score 0):

Set a Bool to NSUserdefaults after a login was successful. Put this Code in your method which is called after a successful login:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"login.state"];
    [defaults synchronize];
// go to your next ViewController
```

Then check in your Appdelegate.m in the didFinishLaunchWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"login.state"] == YES) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        SWRevealViewController *swrvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"revealVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = swrvc;
        [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LoginViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginVC"];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

If you need any help please ask!

Comment: Ok, I'm using Parse SDK. So instead of NSUserDefaults I use the currentUser method to determine if an user is logged in or not. When an user login with success how can I dismiss the login view and set my main view as root? This in the loginViewController.m

Comment: Do it like in the didFinishLaunchWithOptions  Block in my posted code. There is a option with navigationcontroller and one without. Copy this Code and adapt it to your ControllerClasses.